# How do Fabric3 and Tuscany SCA implementations compare?

Tags: sca

There are two open source implementations of SCA; Fabric3 and Apache Tuscany. I was unable to find anything on the web comparing the two. Any experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Our project needs SCA and I did a POC. In short, Tuscany is more like a reference implementation, and Fabric3 is more production ready. Both of the communities are very friendly to provide help. At the end, we chose Fabric3.